# Calling href with Angular to open modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, datatables

**Context**

I´m working in this [Tutorial](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2016/12/crud-operation-using-datatables-aspnet-mvc.html), is about CRUD with DataTable, but difference I´m using Asp.Net WebApi with Angular

I´m into step 9, where tutorial made partial views for pop-up window, but I don´t use partial view, instead it, I use Angular Views

**Problem**

I don´t know how to replace that partial View for my Angular View

**Code**

***View***

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dt-bootstrap no-footer" id="tabla_catalogos" role="grid" aria-describedby="sample_editable_1_info">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="hidden"></th>
      <th style="width: 200px;"> Codigo </th>
      <th> Nombre </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

***JS***

```
    $('#tabla_catalogos')
        .DataTable({
            searching: true,
            dom: 'ftpB',
            autoWidth: false,
            buttons: [
                //'excelHtml5', 'csv', 'print'
            ],
            paging: true,
            select: {
                style: 'single'
            },
            info: false,
            ordering: true,
            "processing": true,
            ajax: {
                method: 'GET',
                url: "../../api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoRegistro/" + selected.ID,
                dataSrc: '',
                beforeSend: function(request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Version", $scope.usuario.Version);
                    request.setRequestHeader("Origen", 'Web');
                }
            },
            columns: [
            { data: 'Catalogo', visible: false, searchable: false },
            { data: 'Codigo' },
            { data: 'ID', visible: false, searchable: false },
            { data: 'Nombre' },
            { data: 'Padre', visible: false, searchable: false },
            {
                data: 'ID',
                render: function(data){
                    return '<a class="popup" href="root.detalleregistros'+data+'">Editar</a>';
                }
            },
             {
                 data: 'ID',
                 render: function (data) {
                     return '<a class="popup" href="root.detalleregistros' + data + '">Eliminar</a>';
                 }
             }

            ],
            pageLength: 10 //,
            //pagingType: "simple_numbers"
            ,
            language: {
                "emptyTable": "No se encontraron registros",
                "zeroRecords": "No encontraron coincidencias",
                "search": "Buscar: "
            }
        });

    $('.tablecontainer').on('click', 'a.popup', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        OpenPopup($(this).attr('href'));
    });

    function OpenPopup(pageUrl) {
        var $pageContent = $('<div/>');
        $pageContent.load(pageUrl, function () {
            $('#popupForm', $pageContent).removeData('validator');
            $('#popupForm', $pageContent).removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');

        });

        $dialog = $('<div class="popupWindow" style="overflow:auto"></div>')
                  .html($pageContent)
                  .dialog({
                      draggable: false,
                      autoOpen: false,
                      resizable: false,
                      model: true,
                      title: 'Popup Dialog',
                      height: 550,
                      width: 600,
                      close: function () {
                          $dialog.dialog('destroy').remove();
                      }
                  })

        $('.popupWindow').on('submit', '#popupForm', function (e) {
            var url = $('#popupForm')[0].action;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $('#popupForm').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status) {
                        $dialog.dialog('close');
                        oTable.ajax.reload();
                    }
                }
            })

            e.preventDefault();
        })
        $dialog.dialog('open');
    }

};
```

***Angular Service, invoke view:***

```
.state('root.detalleregistros', {
                 url: "detalleRegistros.html",
                 templateUrl: "../SPA/administrador/catalogos/detalleRegistros.html",
                 controller: "detalleRegistrosCtrl",
                 authenticate: true
             })
```

When I clic into url as mi code `'<a class="popup" href="root.detalleregistros'+data+'">Editar</a>';` it redirect me to  `http://localhost:55720/admin/root.detalleregistros/1`

instead

`http://localhost:55718/admin/#/detalleRegistros.html`

What I´am doing wrong there? help is very appreciated. Regards

I try `'<a class="popup" ui-sref="root.detalleregistros({data:11})">Editar</a>';` as @Agam Banga comment but modal just don´t open, I need to add something to table view? or what can be wrong there?

Comment: Great @josep :) Please do not post the same question twice, better to update the original post for clarification or elaboration.

Comment: Yes I update this one and delete other post @davidkonrad

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the state for "root.detalleregistros". To Open this state, you need to use the inbuild directive of ui-router which is ui-sref.

```
<a ui-sref="root.detalleregistros">Editar</a>
```

Also, if you want to pass params, you can use

```
<a ui-sref="root.detalleregistros({data:11})">Editar</a>
```

Comment: I do it, but my modal dont open, no error ok console, just dont open

Comment: are you there bro?